# Boostrap datepicker, disabled dates dynamically each month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I can disable dates with:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    datesDisabled: ['03/06/2017', '03/21/2017','04/14/2017']
});
```

but with my use case, since you can go over the year by the calendar, I can have 300 disable days out of 365 in 2017 and 200 disabled days out of 365 in 2016.

I want to optimize, imagine after 5 years, he could have 2500 disabled days to load.
Someone know how to do it dynamically, I mean, each time a change the  current month.

Or another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any of the set* methods (e.g. *setDatesDisabled*) in the *changeMonth*, *changeYear*, *changeDecade* or *changeCentury* events will trigger an update which will cause the picker to revert back to the month in which the current view date occurs.

To prevent this you simply need to initiate the picker with the **updateViewDate** option set to **false**.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  todayHighlight: true,
  updateViewDate: false,
  //datesDisabled: ['03/06/2017', '03/21/2017','04/14/2017']
}).on('changeMonth', function(e){
  var month = e.date.getMonth();
  var disabled = getDisabledDates(month);
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', disabled);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically update disabled dates using [`setDatesDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdatesdisabled) and you can listen to view changes adding handler for [`changeMonth`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changemonth), [`changeYear`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changeyear), [`changeDecade`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedecade) and [`changeCentury`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changecentury) events.

**EDIT:** As Dave Herman stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915571/4131048), there was a bug with version `1.6.4` fixed with `1.7.1` and you have to add [`updateViewDate: false`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#updateviewdate) option.

Here my attempt (unsing `getDisabledDates` function to simulate dynamc disabled dates):

```js
function getDisabledDates(month){
  if( month<0 || month>12){
    return [];
  }
  var disabled = [
    ['01/01/2017', '01/02/2017', '01/03/2017'],
    ['02/04/2017', '02/05/2017', '02/06/2017'],
    ['03/08/2017', '03/09/2017', '03/10/2017'],
    ['04/05/2017', '04/06/2017', '04/07/2017'],
    ['05/15/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/17/2017'],
    ['06/11/2017', '06/12/2017', '06/13/2017'],
    ['07/15/2017', '07/16/2017', '07/17/2017'],
    ['08/07/2017', '08/08/2017', '08/09/2017'],
    ['09/05/2017', '09/06/2017', '09/07/2017'],
    ['10/11/2017', '10/12/2017', '10/13/2017'],
    ['11/06/2017', '11/07/2017', '11/08/2017'],
    ['12/13/2017', '12/14/2017', '12/15/2017'],
  ];
  return disabled[month];
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  todayHighlight: true,
  updateViewDate: false,
  //datesDisabled: ['03/06/2017', '03/21/2017','04/14/2017']
}).on('changeMonth', function(e){
  var month = e.date.getMonth();
  var disabled = getDisabledDates(month);
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', disabled);
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: I didn't know about setDatesDisabled, thank's for the solution, it look perfect, but why I can't change the month ? 
On your snippet and on my project too,
-> change the month by the arrow, it stay on march
-> change the date by cliking on the month, it stay on march

Comment: @xif thank you for pointing it out, I didn't noticed it. It seems that the problem is using one of `datepicker` [methods](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) inside `changeMonth` handler. Maybe it's a bug of the datepicker, I'll try to investigate further.

Comment: I've posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43188409/4131048) (referencing this one) hoping to get an answer to understand why `setDatesDisabled` (and other setters) inside `changeMonth` listner causes problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer updating datepicker version to `1.7.1` (there was a bug in `1.6.4`) and added `updateViewDate: false` after Dave Herman [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915571/4131048) to my related question. Now everything works fine.