# Update option dinamically when user changes month in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) and I have attached a listner to [`changeMonth`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changemonth) event.

If I use one of setters listed [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) (e.g. [`setStartDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getstartdate), [`setDatesDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdatesdisabled), [`setDaysOfWeekHighlighted`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdaysofweekdisabled) etc.) inside my listner, the picker view does not updates (month is unchanged). Everything works fine, if I do not use any datepicker's setter inside my listner.

Here a live sample showing the issue. In this example I'm trying to update dinamically hightlighted dates when the user changes months.

```js
function getHighlighted(month){
  var highlitedDays = [0, 1];
  if( month % 2 == 0 ){
    highlitedDays = [3, 4];
  }
  return highlitedDays;
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: getHighlighted(new Date().getMonth())
}).on('changeMonth', function(e){
  var month = e.date.getMonth();
  var highlightedDays = getHighlighted(month);
  // I use setDaysOfWeekHighlighted just as example
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekHighlighted', highlightedDays);
  // Do something else
  //...
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: getHighlighted(new Date().getMonth())
}).on('changeMonth', function(e){
  console.log("I've just changed month to " + e.date.getMonth());
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2">
```

What am I missing?

I came across this issue when I aswered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43099055/4131048) where I used `setDatesDisabled` inside `changeMonth` listner.

---

**EDIT** (after comments)

I've tried both using `$(this)` inside `'changeMonth'` and assign my datepicker to a variable as shown here:

```
var dt = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: getHighlighted(new Date().getMonth())
})
dt.on('changeMonth', function(e){
  var month = e.date.getMonth();
  var highlightedDays = getHighlighted(month);
  // Neither using dt nor $(this) works
  dt.datepicker('setDaysOfWeekHighlighted', highlightedDays);
  // Do something else
  //...
});
```

but the problem is still there.

Comment: You are instantiating a new datePicker in memory each time you click as a result of this line: var startDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date());

So, you are no longer pointing at your original datePicker, thus the date is not updating on it.

Use the 'this' keyword to refer to the datepicker that your listener is attached to.

Comment: @Korgrue thank you for the comment, I've tried using `this` but I got the same result. Do you have a working snippet using that approach? I've used `$('.datepicker').datepicker('method', arg1, arg2);` because it is suggested in the [docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#methods).

Comment: Try to assign your instiantor it to a variable so that you can reference it directly.

Comment: @Korgrue thank you again for the comment. I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I've edited my question showing my attempts to be sure I had done what you suggested.

Comment: Please see my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753989/2010834) which might resolve your issue.

Comment: Please see my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753989/2010834) which might resolve your issue.

Comment: My answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753989/2010834) might help you resolve this problem.

Comment: @DaveHerman I tried to add `updateViewDate: false` option, but it seems that it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VincenzoC Please make sure you're using the latest version (1.7.1), this Fiddle demonstrates that it works https://jsfiddle.net/s35za9dr/

```
function getHighlighted(month){
  var highlitedDays = [0, 1];
  if( month % 2 == 0 ){
    highlitedDays = [3, 4];
  }
  return highlitedDays;
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: getHighlighted(new Date().getMonth()),
  updateViewDate: false
}).on('changeMonth', function(e){
  var month = e.date.getMonth();
  var highlightedDays = getHighlighted(month);
  // I use setDaysOfWeekHighlighted just as example
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekHighlighted', highlightedDays);
  // Do something else
  //...
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: getHighlighted(new Date().getMonth()),
  updateViewDate: false
}).on('changeMonth', function(e){
  console.log("I've just changed month to " + e.date.getMonth());
});
```

**EDIT**

Using any of the set* methods (e.g. *setDatesDisabled*) in the *changeMonth*, *changeYear*, *changeDecade* or *changeCentury* events will trigger an update which will cause the picker to revert back to the month in which the current view date occurs.

To prevent this you simply need to initiate the picker with the **updateViewDate** option set to **false**.

Comment: Great! There was a bug in version `1.6.4` and `1.7.1` was not released when I posted the question. I think that you have to add `updateViewDate` notes also in this answer to make it clearer. Thank for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Your method update to current date whenever you change the date.

**Solution:** Try following code.

1. Remove your current on change method.
2. Add document Ready for initialize to current date and other is default.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>

   <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2">
   <script>

   $( document ).ready(function() {
   var startDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date());
   });

   $('#datepicker').datepicker().on('change', function(e){
     // I use setStartDate just as example
     var startDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekHighlighted', ['2016-04-29',           '2016-04-30']);

     // Do something else
     //...
   });

   $('#datepicker2').datepicker().on('changeMonth', function(e){
     console.log("I've just changed month to " + e.date.getMonth());
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is not how to update start date.

Comment: Exactly, did you try my code. if not please try first and check.

Comment: Your code may work, but it doesn't help in my case. I have to use datepicker setters (`setStartDate` is just an example) inside `changeMonth` listner. There is no `changeMonth` in your code.

Comment: Okay, one quick hack. just move your datetimepicker library at the top of other js library. i have seen few libraries that stuck like this.

Comment: Sorry but changing import order doesn't help. jQuery must be imported before datepicker, while bootstrap.js is not mandatory and removing it or importing after datepicker does not solves my issue.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works, but it does not cover my usecase, I've updated my question to better explain what is my issue. My problem is how to update options dinamically when the user changes month.

Comment: Hi, code is updated with setDaysOfWeekHighlighted. please check.

Comment: Thank you again, but this version gives error (the argument given to `setDaysOfWeekHighlighted` is wrong, fixing it doesn't help either) and again there is no `changeMonth` in your code. I fear that my issue is still a bit unclear to you. I'll try to edit again to explain it better.